# Trying to install an Apple Watch app but getting error about WatchApp Kit

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, apple-watch-standalone

This is an app that I have previously been able to install - now after install, I get an error 'A WatchKit app within this app is not a valid bundle.' right before it install the app on the watch. The app does not end up being installed on the watch.

For the WatchKit App - I have the following in the info.plist WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier - com.xxxx.xxxx

For the WatchKit Extension - I have WKAppBundleIdentifier - com.xxx.xxx.watchkitapp

What am I missing?